# Как передать 2 значения в meta_query?

Tags: php, массивы, wordpress, веб-программирование, get

Здравствуйте, есть такая штука как meta_query. Нужно чтобы в `value` попадали 2 значения, а не 1 как сейчас.

ПРИМЕР:

`site.com/?color_value=#9ac317&color_value=#b2004b/` в `'value' => $_GET['color_value']` идет только `#b2004b`.

Ниже код для более удобного понимания:

```
if(!empty($_GET['color_value'])) $param_1 = array( 'key' => 'select_color', 'value' => $_GET['color_value'], 'compare' => 'LIKE');

$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'product',        
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' =>'date',
    'order' => 'DESC', 
    'tax_query'=> 
    array( array( 
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 
        'field' => 'id', 
        'terms' => $category_id)),
        'meta_query' => array($param_1)
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

При задании нескольких значений для параметра запроса нужно указывать, что это массив, с помощью [] и убрать #, потому что они имеют специальное значение в url:

```
site.com/?color_value[]=9ac317&color_value[]=b2004b
```

Код должен выглядеть так:

```
$category_id = 0;
$param_1 = array();

var_dump($_GET['color_value']);
echo '<br>';

if(!empty($_GET['color_value'])) {
    $value = $_GET['color_value'];
    if (! is_array( $value) ) {
        $value = array( $value );
    }
    $param_1 = array( 'key' => 'select_color', 'value' => $value, 'compare' => 'LIKE');
}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' =>'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query'=>
        array( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $category_id)),
    'meta_query' => $param_1,
);

var_dump($args);
```

Рабочий пример на моем тестовом сайте: http://test.kagg.eu/wp-content/themes/test/722723.php?color_value[]=9ac317&color_value[]=b2004b

Comment: не совсем хорошо, тогда через var_dump($param_1 = array($param_1)) это значение null

Comment: при чем тут var_dump? я не понял комментария

Comment: я про то что это не верно, так как значение пустое

Comment: Да, там 2 ошибки было, исправил ответ. Теперь с рабочим примером.